# install sound_play in fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use sound_play package in fuerte.
However, I cannot find the sound_play package in my desktop-full ros fuerte.  Do anyone know how to install the sound_play package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93731/install-sound_play-in-fuerte/) by [ldsrogan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3964/ldsrogan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can see here: http://wiki.ros.org/sound_play

Sound_play is part of the audio_common group and can be installed for fuerte via

```
apt-get install ros-fuerte-audio-common
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0